# Enviar featured image do post por e-mail

Tags: wordpress, email

Preciso elaborar uma função que use um formulário (preferencialmente Contact Form 7) onde os visitantes possam indicar aquele post colocando o e-mail de um amigo, e esse amigo deve receber o e-mail com o conteúdo do post e a imagem destacada do mesmo (featured image).

Já tentei com o hook 'wpcf7_before_send_mail' do CF7 mas não tive sucesso, a imagem não é enviada.

Comment: Pode mostrar seu código? Sabe se o hook é chamado ou a falha é só na hora de incluir a imagem como anexo?